# Tcpdump - measure for a fixed amount of time

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

Is it possible to specify the time for how long the `tcpdump` should measure the received and sent packets? 
I know that the command

```
tcpdump -c 100
```

specifies that the `tcpdump` should stop after it received 10 packets. I would like to specify that tcpdump stops after for example 5 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-G` (rotating dump file every x seconds) + `-W` (number of files to rotate)

```
tcpdump -G 300 -W 1 -w file.dump
```